# Read tags in XML then set data to different objects Digester Common

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I have the following XML

```
<data>
  <name> James </name>
  <age> 25 </age>
</data>
```

I try to set the name to a `ClassA` and the age an other `ClassB`.

Is possible do this with `Diggester`?

Comment: All `XML` tags end with `</whatever>` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the XML values and store them into a class, I can suggest two options.

1. `SAXParser`
2. `JAXB`

`SAXParser` is an XML parser which will deliver you data by callback methods. You can know exactly what tag is being processed now and get the data from that tag.

Second is `JAXB` that is `Java Architecture for XML Binding`.

> Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) allows Java developers to map
>   Java classes to XML representations. JAXB provides two main features:
>   the ability to marshal Java objects into XML and the inverse, i.e. to
>   unmarshal XML back into Java objects
>   --Wikipedia

Now what remains is what suits your needs :)

Comment: @user2408040 I have never used `Digester`

Answer (score 0):

Where do the instances of ClassA and ClassB come from? If they exist before you invoke the digester then you can do it using custom rules as follows:

```
String xml = "<data>"
    + "<name>James</name>"
    + "<age>25</age>"
    + "</data>";

final ClassA ca = new ClassA();
final ClassB cb = new ClassB();

Digester digester = new Digester();
digester.addRule("data/name", new Rule() {
  @Override
  public void body(String namespace, String name, String text) throws Exception {
    ca.setName(text);
  }
});
digester.addRule("data/age", new Rule() {
  @Override
  public void body(String namespace, String name, String text) throws Exception {
    cb.setAge(Integer.parseInt(text));
  }
});
digester.parse(new StringReader(xml));
```

If they are created by other parts of the XML parsing then would need to know more about the overall problem.

Cheers